# How to make sure there is no overlap between UNIX timestamp ranges

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have a script that checks whether there is a session already scheduled within the time requested by the user. I need to make sure that the user cannot schedule a session if there is another session in that timeframe. Here is what I've done:

```
//Check to make sure no sessions have been already scheduled for this time

$session_check_query = "SELECT * FROM requested_sessions WHERE username_t = '{$tutor_usernname}'";
$session_check_process = mysql_query($session_check_query);

while ($session_check = mysql_fetch_array($session_check_process)) {
    if ($session_check['time_from'] - $session_to_time <= 900 && $session_check['time_from'] > $session_to_time && $session_check['accepted'] == 1) {
        header("Location:../../../iframes/schedule-session.php?".$url_string."&error=notavail");
        exit;
    }

    if ($session_check['time_from'] <= $session_from_time && $session_check['time_to'] >= $session_to_time && $session_check['accepted'] == 1) {
        header("Location:../../../iframes/schedule-session.php?".$url_string."&error=notavail");
        exit;
    }
}
```

That first "if" statement makes sure that there is no upcoming session within the next 15 minutes, and the second "if" statement makes sure that the time entered does not fall within the range of the scheduled session.

However, let's say there is a session scheduled from 11:00 to 12:00 PM. This code will work fine if I enter let's say 11:15 to 11:30, but if I enter something like 11:30 to 12:15 or 10:45 to 12:15 it will pass the test.

I need the code to make sure that there is no overlap between the time range entered by the user and the sessions that have already been scheduled.

Comment: The test criteria need to be: "The start time of the new session must not be between the start and end times of the earlier session" AND "The end time of the new session must not be between the start and end times of the earlier session". A total of four tests for each of the scheduled sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to know if the selected time ends after the start of the session, and starts before the end of the session.

```
// You obviously need to set these appropriately or change the code below for your needs
$userSelectedStart = 1;
$userSelectedEnd   = 2;
$knownStart        = 3;
$knownEnd          = 4;

if ($userSelectedStart <= $knownEnd && $userSelectedEnd >= $knownStart) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great. Totally helped me out a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requested_sessions WHERE username_t = '{$tutor_usernname}'
    AND
(time_to > ".($session_from_time - 900)." OR  time_from < ".($session_to_time + 900).")";
```

If the end time of a session is bigger than the start time of the new session (minus your required 15 minute break), then they overlap.

If the start time of a session is smaller than the end time of the new session (again, plus your 15 minute break), then they overlap.

Ergo: If COUNT(*) is anything but zero, something overlaps. Of course you can also query the actual data of the sessions that do overlap if you care about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved using a trivial query which returns list of ids for overlapping sessions. While I used variables in query (@S/@E), they can and probably should be replaced with actual values. Also note that you need to subtract those 15minutes from the start time (@S) and add 15minutes to the end time (@E).

SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSION (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  USER_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  START DATETIME NOT NULL,
  END DATETIME NOT NULL 
  );

INSERT INTO SESSION VALUES (1, 'test', '2013-02-10 14:00:00', '2013-02-10 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO SESSION VALUES (2, 'test', '2013-02-10 12:00:00', '2013-02-10 13:30:00');
INSERT INTO SESSION VALUES (3, 'test', '2013-02-10 16:00:00', '2013-02-10 21:30:00');
INSERT INTO SESSION VALUES (4, 'test', '2013-02-10 8:00:00', '2013-02-10 11:30:00');
```

QUERY:

```
SET @S = '2013-02-10 14:40:00';
SET @E = '2013-02-10 16:00:00';
SELECT ID FROM SESSION
 WHERE START <= @S AND END > @S
 OR START > @S AND START <= @E;
```

And here's the SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d958e/6/2

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this together. It is very helpful :)